# Tabela tirar margens no media print

Tags: css

Tenho uma tabela e estou tentando tirar as margens dela na hora da impressão com o media print, entretanto eu já tentei:

```
margin: 0  0 0 0 !important;
padding: 0  0 0 0 !important;
```

E nada funciona e eu preciso de mais espaço na impressão.

Comment: Poste o código para melhor ajudar.

Comment: Quer tirar as margens da tabela ou da "folha"?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
#page td {
   padding:0; margin:0;
}

#page {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

o Dado `border-collapse: collapse;` condensa as bordas em uma.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se seu seletor está sendo aplicado corretamente e que o estilo de impressão está sendo chamado adequadamente.
Ex: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" media="print">`.